# locationManager returns 0.00000, 0.00000 coordinates in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to figure out how to get my location coordinates "currentCentre" in ViewDidLoad, so I can automatically query google for data in my detail view (without clicking anything), the problem is the coordinates are 0.0000,0.0000 initially and google can't query anything, but if I zoom in on the map and then query I return the google results.  How can I fix this, I've read a few places that the locationManager needs more time to find my location, so if that is the problem, what is a one or two liner I can use to create an artificial delay so I can get valid coordinates:

code snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
_mapView.delegate = self;

self.mapView.delegate = self;

[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[self autoQuery];

}

-(void)autoQuery {
NSLog(@"%f", currentCentre.latitude);
NSLog(@"%f", currentCentre.longitude);

[self queryGooglePlaces:@"cafe"]; //]self.detailItem];

NSLog(@"%@",self.detailItem);
}
```

Comment: what is currentCentre ? Your location is reliable only in location manager delegate method `didUpdateLocations:`

Comment: Don't load the map until your get the first location update.

Comment: where is you callback method for `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol? what does that method do exactly?

Comment: Thanks actually I figured out a smarter way to do it, by calling the query within: - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    NSLog(@"%f", currentCentre.latitude);
    [self autoQuerey];
}

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a better way to solve the problem, if you call:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    NSLog(@"%f", currentCentre.latitude);
    [self autoQuery];
}
```

This method will not let you perform the code inside until the locations have been updated, so once updated the internal code will execute.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant in my comment to your question. Keep in mind that your app will get lots of location updates so you will end up calling your `autoQuery` over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use location manager delegate method and update google query there.

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations { [self autoQuery]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

@rmaddy and others who might be curious, I now understand that my previous solution updates constantly, which is not desired (I only want to have the autoQuery run once when the view is opened), so I added the property @property (nonatomic) int count; in the header and used this code to ensure the autoquery is only called once each time the view is opened

```
if (currentCentre.latitude != 0.000000)
{
    if (_count == 0) {
        [self autoQuery];
        _count = _count + 1;
    }
}
```

currentCentre is defined in the interface to get the GPS coordinates with:     CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCentre;

If anyone has a better way or more efficient way please write a comment. thanks